# How to get React Native packager ip from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is there any way to get dynamicly React Native packager ip with port or full path to bundle - `jsCodeLocation` through JavaScript code? It can be `localhost:8081` or `192.168.0.1.xip.io:8081`. It depends on the running device - simulator or real device

Comment: For now, I found it here in javascript console `__fbBatchedBridgeConfig.remoteModuleConfig[2][1].scriptURL`

Comment: This working only in remote chrome debugging

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found [NativeModules in ReactNative source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/970caa4552d4ba87c1a954391535ff42b00832e7/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js) and discover scriptURL here:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

...

const scriptURL = NativeModules.SourceCode.scriptURL;
const address = scriptURL.split('://')[1].split('/')[0];
const hostname = address.split(':')[0];
const port = address.split(':')[1];
```

It works on simulator and device!

Comment: Hi, the code working, i have short code, only get address, require('react-native').NativeModules.SourceCode.scriptURL.split(":").slice(1,-1).join("")

Answer (score 7):

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
import url from 'url';

const { hostname } = url.parse(NativeModules.SourceCode.scriptURL);
```

Answer (score 1):

**2024 Updated version on 0.73 - TurboModules - New Architecture enabled**

```
const SourceCode = TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing("SourceCode");
const scriptURL = SourceCode.getConstants().scriptURL;
const address = scriptURL.split('://')[1].split('/')[0];
const hostname = address.split(':')[0];
const port = address.split(':')[1];
```